# Plant cell question in age 12 science test Part II

Tags: cell-biology, zoology, red-blood-cell

I'm a parent and I think the teacher had been a bit harsh with marking most of these questions but can someone help me answer the very last question on the paper please (where someone has written SP against it). Is the answer mitochondria?

[image]

Comment: As I already mentioned in the other post, questions like this are not generally useful for others because it is not really about a scientific query. The annotations/diagrams are not from a well known book/journal or other such published sources and therefore it is more about having an understanding with the teacher. Moreover, this would be considered a "homework" as per our site standards and such questions are expected to have some research effort from the asker.

Comment: what did the teacher say the answer was?

Comment: HI WYSIWYG I wasn't ignoring you - I didn't see your previous posts in time - I was too busy writing this one out :) But I won't post any more like this now - if anything I might post a question if I've tried many other avenues first together showing where I've checked.

Comment: To Vance I don't know as it was part of a test as I don't think the teacher went over all the answers.

Comment: No problem. You can even use the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1997/the-biosphere) if you have quick questions.

Comment: I would grade alike. The subject might be considered advanced for 12 years old (I would assume the teacher is respecting the program) but the answers that are counted as wrong are quite obviously wrong.

Comment: The question is off-topic here as it is not about science but about teaching. If you happen to have doubts on how to deal with how the grade affects your kid, you might want to ask a question on [parenting.SE](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I will decide what is off topic as I posted the original question I had trouble with.

Comment: The community decides what is off topic, not you @masterSQL

Comment: Or you either !!  Am I not the community as well then? Or does my opinion count for less or something?

Comment: @MasterSQL rg255 is right. You get to decided what is on topic in so much as you can post whatever you feel like posting. Higher rep users can go through questions and nominate questions for closing due to being off topic. If enough nominations are made, the question is closed (This is what rg255 means when they say "the community decides").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to go through the question in total:

(a) Part A nucleus is correct, but Part B ist the cytosol/cytoplasm, as the line does not stop at the border, but goes through it and ends in the gray part of the cell.

(b) For part C, it is the same problem as in your first question. Yes, the picture may be a plant cell, however, upon this drawing one cannot differentiate a mitochondrium from a chloroplast. In my opinion, a good teacher should have marked this answer as correct, even if he/she wanted to hear the other possibility. Part D is correct.

(c) 'Photosynthesis takes place here': Photosynthesis takes place in the chloroplasts. Mitochondria would have been correct, if the teacher would have asked for the respiratory chain or for the often in school simplified powerhouses of the cell.
'Many of the cell's chemical reactions take place here': I think, the teacher wanted to hear the cytosol as answer.

Comment: Hi SeRe I very appreciate your answer, thank you. I think if the very last question had said 'Jelly-like material surrounding the nucleus of a cell; chemical reactions take place here' then it would have given the pupils a better clue so yes the answer is cytoplasm. Thanks again.